# Corresponding windows cmd command for unix command

Tags: windows, unix, cmd, terminal, cut

I am using following unix command on mac to separate out columns in a file:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,10,11,12 < testFile.txt
```

File sample:

```
unzip trace file:
Archive:  /Logs/1.trace/instrument_data/2DFBB7CF-2B32-41D6-9FA6-73CF813DFC24/run_data/1.run.zip
  inflating: Logs/2.trace/instrument_data/2DFBB7CF-2B32-41D6-9FA6-73CF813DFC24/run_data/1.run  


Run 1, starting at 2015/08/06 16:46:35:185, running until 2015/08/06 16:53:30:445
Sample 0: CPU Usage: 2.56% Memory Usage: 5608.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:35:955 
Sample 1: CPU Usage: 1.21% Memory Usage: 5576.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:37:143 
Sample 2: CPU Usage: 2.46% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:38:323 
Sample 3: CPU Usage: 2.49% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:39:502 
Sample 4: CPU Usage: 2.51% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:40:674 
Sample 5: CPU Usage: 2.56% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:41:832 
Sample 6: CPU Usage: 2.21% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:43:009 
Sample 7: CPU Usage: 1.92% Memory Usage: 5560.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:44:202 
Sample 8: CPU Usage: 2.83% Memory Usage: 5572.00 KiB Timestamp: 2015/08/06 16:46:45:408
```

Also below data is junk for me, so i also need to remove it

```
unzip trace file:
    Archive:  /Logs/1.trace/instrument_data/2DFBB7CF-2B32-41D6-9FA6-73CF813DFC24/run_data/1.run.zip
      inflating: Logs/2.trace/instrument_data/2DFBB7CF-2B32-41D6-9FA6-73CF813DFC24/run_data/1.run
```

What would be the corresponding windows cmd command to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure command line syntax

```dos
(for /f "tokens=3-5,10-12" %a in (testfile.txt) do @echo %a %b %c %d %e %f)|find "CPU"
```

The `for /f` command reads the input file and each line readed is splitted in the indicated tokens using spaces and tabs as delimiters, storing each of the tokens in a separate replaceable parameter alphabetically consecutive to the indicated starting replaceable parameter (`%a` in previous code). The code after the `do` clause is executed for each input line. The full output of the command is filtered with `find` to only show the required lines.

The posted code is written to be executed from command line. Inside batch files the percent signs need to be escaped doubling them, so, `%a` should be `%%a`, `%b` should be `%%b`, ...